# Polymer iron-ajax sending data from paper input

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I am trying to send data from paper input to server via iron-ajax but I cant find a way to get the data correctly. I'm getting a error message saying that my request body is missing.

```
<paper-material id="todoEntry" elevation="2"> 
            <paper-input id="usuario" label="Usuário" required></paper-input> 
            <paper-input id="tipo" label="Tipo" required></paper-input> 
            <paper-input id="nomeItem" label="Item" required></paper-input> 
            <paper-input id="quantidade" label="Quantidade" required></paper-input> 
            <paper-input id="vencimento" label="Vencimento" required></paper-input> 
            <paper-fab icon="icons:add" on-tap="doPost"></paper-fab> 
</paper-material>
        <iron-ajax id="itemPost" url="inventario" method="POST" contentType="application/json" handle-as="json" on-response="_refresh" verbose></iron-ajax>
```

-

```
doPost : function(e) {  
        this.$.itemPost.body = JSON.stringify(e.model);
        this.$.itemPost.generateRequest(); }
```

The reference to e.model above is undefined, how can i get the values from paper inputs?

Comment: You can find paper-input elements and then add their value to request body. Example: `this.$.tipo.value` - value of one paper-input element. For another similar

Comment: Is there a way to reference the paper fields from the model? I did something similar from inside a dom-repeat, but cant do the same with the paper fields.

Comment: If you data-bind your paper-inputs to a property then you could. For instance: `<paper-input id="quantidade" label="Quantidade" value="{{quantidade}}" required></paper-input>`. Then when you build up your JSON object you can reference the properties.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using <iron-form> ?.